# Dynamically Insert Image Into Stylesheet

Tags: templates, advanced-custom-fields, media-library

Let's say I have a banner image I want to act as a background cover. Users manually upload their image with the Media library, which then associates that image with the post (image is handled using ACF).

Is there a way to have WP inject that image into a stylesheet? This doesn't seem possible given the WP loop only residing in the HTML template but I thought somebody might have an idea.

Comment: You can use WordPress Filesystem API to dynamically store contents in a file. Trigger that on saving the custom header.

Comment: Abhik - curious if you can elaborate on this method with a full on answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing complected.. Just have a look here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API

Comment: Thanks Abhik - just using the template method mentioned below seems to be the best solution with the least overhead. It's also server-side, so I dont have to worry about people not seeing the bg image render (another concern I've had debating different methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically with themes that support custom styles/images, you define everything you can in your stylesheet, and then add the dynamic styles inline:

```
.header {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat:
    background-size: whatever;
}
```

And in your templates:

```
<div class="header"<?php if ( $image ) printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"', $image ) ?>>
   Title
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking about doing. I'll probably accept it as the right answer, just want to see if there are any other creative ways to go about this.

Comment: The only other viable alternative I see is storing all your customisations in a generated file/linking to a script that serves a stylesheet, and quite frankly (unless you've got *heaps* of custom styles), is just not worth it.

Comment: Again, similar to what I was thinking. You'd have to insert the image SRCs with JS - and that seemed uglier than inline style declarations being generated by the templating system.

Comment: This really is a pretty easy method to implement and it's working great - thanks TheDeadMedic.